# Display A Div When Two Links Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am making a plugin for social discount. When user click on Facebook and Instagram follow link then it display a coupon box.

The div display only when user click on both the links. I am not good in java-script so please help me.

```
<div class="popup">

<div class="social-links">
    <h3>Like + Follow = Get Rs 50 Discount</h3>
    <a href="fb://page/2288133548123387" target="_blank" rel="alternate noopener noreferrer"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="" />Facebook</a>
    <a href="instagram://user?username=kidsfitter" target="_blank" rel="alternate noopener noreferrer"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="" />Instagram</a>
</div>  

<div class="coupon">
    <p>Congratulations: Your Coupon Code is "Discount50". Use it in Checkout Page.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

So I want user click on Facebook link and Like Page and then back to website and click on Instagram link and follow the Page. and then he back to website the coupon div display.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it (using css):

```js
var instagramClicked = false;
var facebookClicked = false;

document.getElementById('instagram').addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.instagramClicked = true;
  this.showCoupon();
});

document.getElementById('facebook').addEventListener('click', () => {
  this.facebookClicked = true;
  this.showCoupon();
});

function showCoupon() {
  if (this.instagramClicked && this.facebookClicked) {
    setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('coupon').style = 'display: block', 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">

<div class="social-links">
    <h3>Like + Follow = Get Rs 50 Discount</h3>
    <a href="" target="_blank" rel="alternate noopener noreferrer" id="facebook"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="" />Facebook</a>
    <a href="" target="_blank" rel="alternate noopener noreferrer" id="instagram"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="" />Instagram</a>
</div>  

<div class="coupon" style="display: none;" id="coupon">
    <p>Congratulations: Your Coupon Code is "Discount50". Use it in Checkout Page.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfect. I need one favor. can we delay display of coupon div for 3 secs ? when user clicked both the link then coupon div display after 3 secs. Regards

Comment: i modified the answer by adding `setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('coupon').style = 'display: block', 1000);` which you can use to delay the display. you can change the `1000` (1000 milliseconds) to what ever value (you wanted 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

add id attributes for links and style attribute, what hide your coupon block like this

```
<div class="popup">

<div class="social-links">
    <h3>Like + Follow = Get Rs 50 Discount</h3>
    <a href="fb://page/2288133548123387" target="_blank" rel="alternate noopener noreferrer" id="facebook-link"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="" />Facebook</a>
    <a href="instagram://user?username=kidsfitter" target="_blank" rel="alternate noopener noreferrer" id="instagram-link"><img src="images/facebook-logo.png" alt="" />Instagram</a>
</div>

<div class="coupon" style="display: none;">
    <p>Congratulations: Your Coupon Code is "Discount50". Use it in Checkout Page.</p>
</div>
```

Then add below, variables what keep state (clicked or not) links, click handlers, and function what check is clicked variables like this.

```
<script>

var facebookClicked = false;
var instagramClicked = false;

document.querySelector("#facebook-link").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    facebookClicked = true;
    showCoupon();
});

document.querySelector("#instagram-link").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    instagramClicked = true;
    showCoupon();
});

function showCoupon() {
    if (facebookClicked && instagramClicked) {
        document.querySelector(".coupon").removeAttribute("style");
    }
}

</script>
```